# JS controller - get all aura:attribute

Tags: javascript-controller, aura-attribute

I've got component with some attributes. For example:

```
<aura:attribute name="missedCalls" type="List" access="global" />

<aura:attribute name="tryingToInitiateCall" type="Boolean" access="global" />
```

I do not know how many of them are in the component nor their names. I am trying to implement universal static resource logger.

So my question is: is it possible to iterate through all of them in the controller (get their names, values) and don't change anything in that component (adding class, id etc.).

I have tried

```
var attributes = $("aura:attribute");
```

, but it is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider that the `.cmp` is transformed into HTML by the framework so `aura:attribute` will not be present in the HTML.

Comment: And I don't see anything in the [documented API](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:Component) that would help so you might have to rely on a fragile reverse engineered solution to do this directly in the JavaScript if this is really important to you. Or you could write some build-time tools that parse the .cmp files and generated JSON you could reference.